# Rails Import CSV with associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, csv, import, datatable

I am newbie to Rails. Now I have these files and a 'jobs.csv' file.

**company.rb**

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**job.rb**

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company

  def self.jobs_import
    jobs = []
    columns = [:title, :level, :salary, :description, :short_des, :requirement, :category, :company_id]

    CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join("lib", "jobs.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
      jobs << {title: row["name"], level: row["level"], salary: row["salary"], description: row["description"], short_des: row["benefit"], requirement: row["requirement"], category: row["type"]}
    end

    Job.import columns, jobs
  end
end
```

Company migration files

```
create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email, unique: true
      t.text :description
      t.string :address
      t.string :company_code

      t.timestamps
    end
```

Job migration file

```
create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :level
      t.string :salary
      t.string :other_salary
      t.text :description
      t.text :short_des
      t.text :requirement
      t.integer :category
      t.datetime :post_date
      t.datetime :expiration_date
      t.references :company, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
```

Now I want to import data to Job table that references to Job table. Please help me! Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Edit **job.rb**

```
jobs << {title: row["name"], level: row["level"], salary: row["salary"], description: row["description"], short_des: row["benefit"], requirement: row["requirement"], category: row["type"], company_id: Company.find_by(company_code: row["company id"])&.id}
```

Comment: add a company_id to the jobs table.

Comment: What do you mean by 'references to Job table'? Did you mean to put 'references a company' here?

Comment: I have solved this problem, just edit the jobs array in job.rb: 

jobs << {title: row["name"], level: row["level"], salary: row["salary"],
               description: row["description"], short_des: row["benefit"],
               requirement: row["requirement"], category: row["type"],
               company_id: Company.find_by(company_code: row["company id"])&.id}